# Does intall target always depends on ALL_BUILD target in a C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake

I ask this question just out of curiosity. Usually when you build a C++ project with CMake, it will contain two targets:

```
ALL_BUILD
install
```

If I understand well, install target always depends on ALL_BUILD, and do you have some counter-examples that do not follow this rule? Thanks

Comment: `install` target always depends on `all`(or ALL_BUILD). Precisely which behaviour should expose counter-example you ask for?

Comment: Always depends, except when CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY is set to ON. I'm not sure this counts as counter-example.